# Integrating inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, proof-verification

Suppose $g$ is a strictly growing function on the interval $[a,b]$ and that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are differentiable. Show that
$$\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx + \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} g^{-1}(x) dx = bg(b)-ag(a) .$$
Here's how I tried:
$$ \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx = 
 xg(x) \bigg|^{b}_{a} 
- \int_{a}^{b} x g'(x) dx 
=bg(b)-ag(a) - \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} g^{-1}(u) du,$$
$$ u = g(x) $$
And so my idea is that 
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} g^{-1}(x) dx - \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} g^{-1}(u) du = 0$$
and thus we're done but I'm guessing I'm wrong so if anyone could correct me that'd be great.

Comment: Your proof is correct. What's the matter in your opinion?

Comment: Oh cool!. Normally something goes wrong...

Comment: Notice that the relation holds even if $g$ is not  differentiable. See the Wikipedia article "integral of inverse function" (that I wrote).

Comment: You can also look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115222/show-rigorously-that-the-sum-of-integrals-of-f-and-of-its-inverse-is-bfb-af/1115317#1115317).

Answer (score 2):

You can also see [Young's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality)

[image: picture]