# Why $\int _c^df^{-1}\left(y\right)\:dy+\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx=b\cdot d-a\cdot c$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, geometry, definite-integrals

Why $\int _c^df^{-1}\left(y\right)\:dy+\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx=b\cdot d-a\cdot c$ ? where f is an bijective function and $f(a)=b,f(c)=d,$
I don't understand graph... I can't see on graph this equality, so have somebody patience to explain me on graph this equality?

I think it is not duplicate, because he wants a rigorous proof, not a draw, and I want to understand from graph, I think is not duplicate... I don't know why they think is duplicate

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ the left hand side is $$\dfrac{1}{2}((d^2+b^2)-(c^2+a^2))$$ which is clearly not the same as the right-hand side. For instance, take $d=1$, the rest 0. Is there some additional assumption you are not relaying?

Comment: can you explain on graph, this equality?

Comment: @Lucas: You forgot to stipulate $f(a) = b, f(c) = d$, as is stated in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Maybe edit your post then to include the assumptions $f(a)=c$, $f(b)=d$, and that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @pizza this is not duplicate, because he want a rigorous proof, not a draw, and I want to understand from graph, I think is not duplicate... I don't know why they think is duplicate

Comment: There is a graph [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154459/integrating-inverse-function?lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without reference to a "graph," note that if we have $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, then

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_c^d f^{-1}(y) \,\,dy &=\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_a^b f^{-1}(f(x)) f'(x) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_a^b x f'(x) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b f(x)+x f'(x) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b (xf(x))' \,\,dx\\\\
&=bf(b)-af(a)\\\\
&=bd-ac
\end{align}$$

.

Comment: please... can you make me to understand graph? I suppose $\int _c^d\:f\left(y\right)dy\:+\:\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx$ is all who's mark with red

Comment: Sure.  For the graph, the shaded areas are give by $b \times d$ less the small "box", which has area $a \times c$.  Does that help?

Comment: The answer is $bd - ac$.  Since $b>a$ and $d>c$, then $bd - ac>0$.

Comment: so $b\cdot d$  is all areas, excepting $a\cdot c$ ?

Comment: $b \times d$ is the area of the "big box" and $a \times c$ is the area of the "small box."  The difference is the sum of the areas under (1) $f$ from $a$ to $b$ and (2) $f^{-1}$ from $c$ to $d$.

Comment: after $b\cdot d\:-\:a\cdot c$ how will see graph? all red? the "small box"  will be red?

Comment: The "graph" of the sum of the areas will look like a "big box" with a smaller box cut from its lower corner.

Comment: and the red stripe between f and f^-1 will disappear?

Comment: That "stripe" represents $f$ and the image of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: the "small box" includes white area ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: why $b\cdot d$ is not a $Point\:\left(b,d\right)$ ?

Comment: One multiplies $b$ and $d$ to find an area.  So, $b \times d$ is just a number.  The physical interpretation of that one number is the amount of space a box of length $b$ and height $d$ occupies.  Make sense now?

Comment: yes, I was confused with xOy axis when denote coordinates, but I suppose we can note $b\cdot d\:=\:P\left(b,\:d\right)$

Comment: however thank you with all my heart, you are a patient and good person and I am wondering because there exist people like you... nice to meet you and good luck in what you do ! you was my hero, because tomorrow I'll take an examination

Comment: You are more than welcome!  Your kind words mean a lot to me ... more than you know.  It has been my pleasure - just glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Not true!

Take $f(x)=x$ - it is a bijection.

Then $f^{-1}(x)=x$, and
$$
\int_c^d f^{-1}(y)\,dy+\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}(d^2-c^2)+\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2) \ne bd-ac.
$$
However, if $c=f(a)$, and $d=f(b)$, then it holds! Simply draw the figure of the graph of $f$. Then $f^{-1}$ is also visible in the same graph (reflection along $y=x$). Then $bd-ac$ is the area under $f$ plus the area under $f^{-1}$ (reflected) in the interval $[a,b]$ in the $x$ direction.