# How to simplify expression $\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx \ ?$

Tags: calculus

How to simplify expression

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx \ ?$$

The answer is $bf(b)-af(a)$  but I am wondering how to get the answer.

Comment: its easy use the symmetry of  inverse and the function about y=x line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical proof (that doesn't assume that $f$ is differentiable).

Take a look at the following figure :

[image]

The colored areas constitute a rectangle whose area can be computed in two ways :

A) globally, as :

$$\text{length} \times \text{width} \  = \ b.f(b)\tag{1}$$

B) by considering it as partitionned into three non-overlapping regions :

- the blue region (deep blue + light blue) : its area is the area under the curve of $f$ starting at $a$ and ending at $b$ i.e., $\int_a^b f(x)dx$,
- the red region (deep red + light red) : its area is the area under the curve of $f^{-1}$, starting at $f(a)$ and ending at $f(b)$, i.e., $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx$ (one has to turn his head 90° !),
- the green region, a rectangle whose area is : $a.f(a)$.

Equating the two ways of computing this area, we get :

$$b.f(b)=\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx + a.f(a)$$

which is equivalent to the relationship you want to establish.

Addendum : It has taken me some time to spot an analogous question. Here it is, on this site : [Show rigorously that the sum of integrals of $f$ and of its inverse is $bf(b)-af(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115222) with some very interesting answers (the accepted answer of Julian Aguirre, and the answer of Kobe ; the answer of Vim is the same as mine). Another reference : [Prove that $\int_a^bf(x)dx+ \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y)dy=bf(b)-af(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/562960).

Last but not least, a generalisation of the equation at hand is given by **Young's inequality** : (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/YoungsInequality.html) as remarked in this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1154557).

Comment: @Peter Szilas You shouldn't have deleted your answer : it was perfectly correct, with the introductory comment " Let us assume that $f$ is differentiable". I strongly advise you to undelete it.

Comment: Thank you very much.