# Prove $xf(x) - \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt = \int_{f(0)}^{f(x)} g(t) \,dt, g(x) = f^{-1}(x), \forall f(x)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse

I have proved it for all functions of the form $f(x) = x^{a}, \forall a, x,$ but I am not sure if it is true for all functions.

---

**Proposition**

$$xf(x) - \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt = \int_{f(0)}^{f(x)} g(t) \,dt, g(x) = f^{-1}(x), \forall f(x)$$

---

**Proof**

Let $f(x) = x^{a}, a \neq -1$, then:

$f(x)x = x^{a + 1}$,

$F(x) = \frac{1}{a + 1} x^{a + 1}$,

$F(0) = 0$, and

$f(x)x - \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt = \color{lime}{\frac{a}{a + 1} x^{a + 1}}$.

Since $f(x) = x^{a}, g(x) = x^{\frac{1}{a}}$,

$G(x) = \frac{a}{a + 1} x^{\frac{a + 1}{a}}$,

$G(f(x)) = \frac{a}{a + 1} x^{a + 1}$,

$G(f(0)) = 0$, and

$G(f(x)) - G(f(0)) = \color{lime}{\frac{a}{a + 1} x^{a + 1}}$.

---

Let $f(x) = x^{a}, a = -1$, then:

$f(x)x = 1$,

$F(x) = \ln|x|$,

$F(0) = -\infty$, and

$f(x)x - \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt = \color{lime}{\infty}$.

Since $f(x) = x^{a}, g(x) = x^{a}$,

$G(x) = \ln|x|$,

$G(f(x)) = -\ln|x|$,

$G(f(0)) = -\infty$, and

$G(f(x)) - G(f(0)) = \color{lime}{\infty}$.

---

I believe that there may be a few exceptions to this, but I am not sure.

I am not sure as to whether or not this formula has been derived / used before.

If you would like to see how I derived it, please, ask me!

Comment: @TimRaczkowski I know that.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski It was not your fault! :-)

Comment: See tris previous [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115222/show-rigorously-that-the-sum-of-integrals-of-f-and-of-its-inverse-is-bfb-af/1115317#1115317).

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thank you for sharing this with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Leibniz's Rule) to show that the derivatives of the LHS and RHS wrt $x$ are identical ($=xf'(x)$).

Which means that LHS = RHS $+ c$.

All you need to do now is to show $c=0$ and that's trivial by taking $x=0$.

Comment: Ah, nice. Thank you very much. Leibniz' rule seems to pop up in many areas of calculus. I should really check it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true for all invertible functions. Think of the integrals in terms of areas under graphs; notice that the areas from the two integrals combine to form an $x$ by $f(x)$ rectangle. (This seems similar to integration by parts; maybe there's a proof using it)

Comment: Yes, that is how I derived the formula. Ah, well, that is great! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this a well-known formula? I judge by the speed of your response that it is.

Comment: No, it's not well known; at least, not that I know of.