# The value of the integral $\int_0^2\left(\sqrt{1+x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\:\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, radicals

The value of definite integral $$\int\limits_{0}^{2}\left(\sqrt{1+x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\:\right)dx$$ is $$(A)\,4 \quad(B)\,5 \quad (C)\,6  \quad(D)\,7$$

My attempt:

I tried using $\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$ but not working. I tried putting $x^3+1=\tan^2\theta$, its also not working.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You do not give any restriction on the method of solution. Why not just do numerical integration using WolframAlpha, software, or a good calculator? The answer seems to be (C) $6$, by the way. I used my TI-Nspire CX. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2B%28x%5E2%2B2x%29%5E%281%2F3%29%29) gives a horrendous indefinite integral. You could even use Simpson's rule on a few points to get a good-enough answer for multiple choice.

Comment: @RoryDaulton,Sir if calculators are not allowed,can we solve it otherwise.

Comment: You could use the trapezoidal rule with three points. You can easily find $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=5$, and can approximate $f(1)\approx 2.9$. The trapezoidal rule then gives the integral approximation $$\frac 12\cdot 1+2.9+\frac 12\cdot 5=5.9$$ Simpson's rule, just a little harder, gives about $5.87$. Either of these gives the answer (C).

Comment: I just realized that the trapezoidal rule with just two points, $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=5$, gives the value $\frac 12\cdot (2-0)(1+5)=6$: You can't get much easier than that! That is possibly what you were meant to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Hint.** The function $ x \mapsto f(x):=\sqrt{1+x^3}$ is strictly increasing on $[0,2]$, then you may use the following [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115222/show-rigorously-that-the-sum-of-integrals-of-f-and-of-its-inverse-is-bfb-af?rq=1):

> $$
> \int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx=b{f(b)}-a{f(a)} \tag1
> $$

(here $ x \mapsto f^{-1}(x+1)=\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2-1}=\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x},\quad f^{-1}(0+1)=0,\,f^{-1}(2+1)=2$) obtaining

> $$I=2\sqrt{1+2^3}-0\sqrt{1+0^3}=\color{red}{6}$$

as suggested.

Comment: amazing solution liked it

Answer (score 10):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}$. $\\$ 
Easily show that $f^{-1}(x+1)=\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}$.

You are asked to find $$\int_0^2 f(x)dx +\int_0^2 f^{-1}(x+1)dx \\ =\int_0^2f(x)dx+\int_1^3 f^{-1}(x)dx \\ =\int_0^2f(x)dx+\int_{f(0)}^{f(2)}f^{-1}(x)dx$$.
Draw a picture.

Comment: ,Sir how will we calculate $\int\limits_{0}^{2}f(x)dx+\int\limits_{f(0)}^{f(2)}f^{-1}(x)dx$

Comment: You should be able to draw a picture and see for yourself. You may also consult [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions). If still nothing, see Olivier's answer.

Comment: @nospoon ) Can you please tell me how $\int_0^2f^{-1}(x+1)\,dx=\int_1^3f^{-1}(x)\,dx$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 substitute $t=x+1$. Also here a picture could help. We're just shifting the whole function to the right by a unit.

Answer (score 6):

I have one more way to do this:

Let $$I_1=\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x^3+1} \:dx$$ By Integration by parts we get

$$I_1=x\sqrt{x^3+1} \bigg|_{0}^{2}-\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^3 dx}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}} \tag{1}$$

Now let $$I_2=\int_{0}^{2} (x^2+2x)^{\frac{1}{3}}dx$$ Use substitution $x^2+2x=t^3$ we get

$(2x+2)dx=3t^2dt$ that is

$dx=\frac{3t^2dt}{2(x+1)}$

But $(x+1)^2-1=t^3$ $\implies$

$x+1=\sqrt{t^3+1}$

Also the limits will be again $0$ and $2$

Thus

$$I_2=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3t^3dt}{2(x+1)}=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3t^3dt}{2\sqrt{t^3+1}}$$  since $t$ is Dummy variable

$$I_2=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3x^3dx}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}} \tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$I_1+I_2=x\sqrt{x^3+1} \bigg|_{0}^{2}=6$$