# Proof of integral identity using integration by parts

Tags: integration

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and increasing, then the inverse $f^{-1}$ exists and

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx = f(b)b - f(a)a.$$

This is obvious by looking at a graph where the integrals are areas of regions that cover a rectangle of area $f(b)b$ with a rectangle of area $f(a)a$ removed.

I recall this is proved rigorously using integration by parts but I can't reconstruct the proof.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your limits for the second integral should be $$\int\limits_{f(a)}^{f(b)}$$

Comment: Integration by parts seems would not work, since $f$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: The correct question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115222/show-rigorously-that-the-sum-of-integrals-of-f-and-of-its-inverse-is-bfb-af

Comment: Fixed limits in edit -- obvious typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$I=\int f^{-1}(x)dx$$
$x=f(u)\Rightarrow dx=f'(u)du$:
$$I=\int f'(u)\cdot (f^{-1}\circ f)(u)du$$
$$I=\int uf'(u)du$$
Integration by parts: $$dV=f'(u)du\qquad U=u\\V=f(u)\qquad dU=du$$
$$\therefore I=UV-\int VdU$$
$$\therefore I=uf(u)-\int f(u)du$$
$$\therefore I=xf^{-1}(x)-(F\circ f^{-1})(x)+C$$
You can go from here

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is exactly what I was trying to remember.  Naturally we need another condition that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: None of the "duplicate" answers take this approach.

Comment: You're very welcome