# How can we evaluate this integral from the 2020 UC Berkeley Integration Bee?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, contest-math

$$I = \int_1^2 \left(e^{1-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}} +1\right) + \left(1 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \log(x-1)} }\right)\mathrm{d}x$$.

From what I have read it has to do with forming a triangle, but I do not know where this comes from. If someone can please explain the evaluation of this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You currently have unmatched brackets. Fix that to make the problem clear

Comment: We even can't edit your post. Pay attention to the comment of @h-squared please

Comment: My apologies, it was a careless mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The correct form of the integral (see the [video](https://youtu.be/Tt3xuD8mCXg?t=295)) is:
$$
I = \int_1^2 \left( e^{1-\frac1{(x-1)^2}}+ 1\right)
+
\left( 1+
\frac1
{\sqrt{1-\log(x-1)}}
\right)\,dx.
$$
This equals
$$
\int_1^2 (f(x) + f^{-1}(x))\,dx
$$
where $f(x):=\exp\left({1-\frac1{(x-1)^2}}\right)+1$. Check that $f$ is increasing and $f(1)= 1$ and $f(2)= 2$, so the value of the integral is
$$
2f(2)-1f(1)=3
$$
using [the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115222/215011) $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = bf(b)-af(a).$$ This is much easier to see geometrically: Borrowing a picture from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1115254/215011), you can visualize the integral as the area of an elbow-shaped region:

[image]

which in this case can be decomposed into three squares of unit area.