# Is there any trick to calculate $\int\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})dx$ faster?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})dx$$
To evaluate the integral we can apply integral by parts (using $u=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$ and $dv=dx$). but my question is: is there other approach to evaluate the integral faster? I think there might be something because we can write it as:

$$\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\times\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)=\ln\left(\cfrac1{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)=-\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$$
But I don't know how to use this.

Comment: See this link:https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralsWithRoots.aspx

Comment: Faster and simpler than by parts in this case ?! I greatly doubt it...

Comment: @DonAntonio it has a little long calculations (finding derivative of $\ln()$ and so on lots of algebraic calculations. )

Comment: @philomath Not really: the derivative is just $\;\cfrac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\;$ ...check it.

Comment: @DonAntonio So the question is can we find this derivative easier? or should  use chain rule and simplify the expression ...?

Comment: Use chan rule and do the easy simplification, of course.

Comment: @MartinR I knew how to use integral by parts. this question is about possibility of using the formula I mentioned to evaluate it easier.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you I got it.

Answer (score 4):

Use $x=\cosh t$

$$\int \sinh t \ln(\cosh t + \sinh t) dt = \int t \sinh t dt = t\cosh t - \sinh t$$

then substitute back.

Comment: +1..but IMHO I will put the constant :-)

Comment: This is nice, recognizing the integrand as $\;\text{arsinh}\, x\;$ ...but I don't think it is faster or simpler than integration by parts.

Comment: @Sebastiano haha my bad. I've been in the habit of problem writing for an integration bee, no $+C$s there.

Comment: @DonAntonio one thing I did not explain clearly was how I did the last step. I "guessed" the antiderivative needed a $t\cosh t$ term, and then asked what did I need to subtract to get the integrand I want after differentiating. It is a less systematic, but faster, equivalent method to by parts.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Perhaps it is a matter of opinion, but I can't see how is this faster than by parts. Simply substituting back is already longer...

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is an inverse function and hence IBP is standard (see below). As soon as you recognize
$$
\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})=\mbox{arcosh}(x)
$$
you can **simplify the IBP computations**, since no computation is really needed:

The following formula holds for any continuous bijective function:
$$
\int f^{-1}(x) dx= x f^{-1}(x)- \int x (f^{-1})'(x) dx = x  f^{-1}(x)- \int f( f^{-1}(x)) (f^{-1})'(x) dx \\
 = x  f^{-1}(x)- \int f(u) du $$

*[Side note: there is a picture proof of this formula in the Book "Proofs without Words".
The proof is basically just observing that
$$
\int_{a}^x f(x) dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(x)} f^{-1}(u) du 
$$
graphically the signed between the rectangle with corners $(0,0), (0,f(x)), (x,0), (x,f(x))$ and the rectangle with corners $(0,0), (0,f(a)), (a,0), (a,f(a))$
The picture proof can be seen [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1115254/9176).
]*

Now set
$$f(x)= \cosh(x) \\
f^{-1}(x)=\mbox{arcosh}(x)$$
and integrate $\int \cosh(u) du$.

If you accept the above formula as a "trick", then that's it.

**Note** Whenever when you know the integral of a bijection $f(x)$, the above formula gives you the integral of $f^{-1}$.

Since the formula is just IBP, it explains why $\int \ln(x) dx, \int \arcsin(x) ds$.... are always easy to calculate by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$\int\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)dx=\int \cosh^{-1}xdx \overset{IBP}=x \cosh^{-1}x -\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

Comment: I remember the $\mathrm{settcos\, h}$ if I not have done a mistake. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano - what is settcos.

Comment: I add the link in Italian language :-( sigh...but you can see the operator sett cos h and sett sin h. I think that the operator is defined only in Italian language: https://www.youmath.it/lezioni/analisi-matematica/integrali/612-integrali-con-sostituzioni-iperboliche.html