# Property of Integral of a strictly increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $0 < a < b$. Let $f > 0$ be continuous and strictly increasing on $[a, b]$. Prove
that $\int_a^b f + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} = bf(b) - af(a)$

By drawing the graph I can see and prove the theorem holds. Area of Outer rectangle - inner rectangle gives the sum of two integrands. How to prove theoretically?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115222/42969

Comment: And many more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1115222?lq=1.