# Sum of function and its inverse

Tags: integration, continuity, set-partition

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and maps $[0,1]$ one-to-one onto $[0,1]$. Therefore, it is obvious that inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists. Then, show that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x) d x+\int_{0}^{1} f^{-1}(y) d y=1
$$
and give a geometric interpretation of this equation.

There is a similar problem in the following link; however, the major strategy does not work since $f$ is not an increasing function. Moreover, the substitution method does not work as well, since we need compact interval $[0, 1]$ for integration. So, what other alternatives are there for solving this problem?

[Show rigorously that the sum of integrals of $f$ and of its inverse is $bf(b)-af(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115222/show-rigorously-that-the-sum-of-integrals-of-f-and-of-its-inverse-is-bfb-af)

Comment: Does it map $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$ ?

Comment: Not necessary, $f(0)$, $f(1)$ can be different from zero, one, respectively. If it would be, then this problem could be easily derived from the provided link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false if $f$ is decreasing.
Consider $f(x) = 1 - x^2$ on $[0,1]$. Then $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$ but
$$
\int_0^1 (1-x^2) \ dx + \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x} \ dx = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{3} \ne 1
$$

If $f$ is increasing, we can interpret the result geometrically as follows: The area under the graph of $f$ plus the area under the graph of $f^{-1}$ is equal to the area of the unit square, which is $1$.

Comment: If $f$ is not decreasing, would it be necessarily true as well? Which conditions would be enough to ensure this holds true? Is it the fact $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ playing crucial role to conclude the correctness of this problem?

Comment: It seems that if $f$ was given an increasing function, then $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ would satisfy, and we could proceed on the provided link problem, right?!

Comment: @Snowflake yes, if $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$, then we can apply the linked result. See also the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for coming up with such counterexample.