# Where can I find a text with this result?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I ran into [$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = b \cdot f(b) - a \cdot f(a) - \int\limits_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dx$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986800/int-limits-ab-fx-dx-b-cdot-fb-a-cdot-fa-int-limits-fa) today and was surprised to find that it has come up on the Math GRE.

I consider myself to like analysis quite a bit, so I was shocked to see this result. Are there any texts that cover this result, and on what page(s)?

Comment: I'm not sure about texts, but you can see it pretty easily from graphical arguments. You could probably also view it as an integral equivalent to the inverse function theorem.

Comment: I might have seen in it in the Spivak's Calculus, but I am not sure, that was 25 years ago.

Comment: See [integral of inverse functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions), especially the [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/FunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg/500px-FunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg.png).

Comment: Depending on the level of generality of the integrand, this may be best treated with integration by parts in a Stieltjes integral. I seem to recall seeing something about this in Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*, which discusses Riemann-Stieltjes integration.

Comment: @Arjang It is indeed in Spivak's *Calculus*. Chapter 13, Exercise 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof of this formula can be given based on Theorems 7.6 and 7.7 of *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom Apostol, concerning Riemann-Stieltjes integration. (The formula itself does not appear to be proved there, however.)

Specifically, let $f$ be a strictly monotonic bijection of an interval $[a,b]$ onto one of the intervals $[f(a),f(b)]$ or $[f(b),f(a)]$. Since $f$ is continuous, it is integrable with respect to $d\alpha$ for the integrator $\alpha(x) = x$. (This is simply a Riemann integral.) By Theorem 7.6 (integration by parts), $\alpha(x) = x$ is integrable with respect to $df$, and we have
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx + \int_a^b x \, df(x) = bf(b) - af(a).$$

Now apply the change of variables theorem 7.7 to $\int_a^b x \, df$, taking $g$ to be the inverse function $f^{-1}$. We obtain
$$\int_a^b x \, df(x) = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(x) \, d[f(g(x))] = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) \, dx,$$
completing the proof.

**Note** Even though the end result can be stated solely in terms of ordinary Riemann integrals, if we restrict ourselves only to garden-variety substitution and integration by parts in Riemann integrals, we find that the proof requires continuous differentiability of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. The basic theorems on Stieltjes integration however yield a more general statement with no additional effort.

Comment: I appreciate the Spivak reference as well. Thank you!