# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi f^{-1} (x) dx$ with $f(x)=\cos x+ x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\cos x+ x$. Evaluate $$\int_0^\pi f^{-1} (x) dx.$$

I used the substitution $x=f(y)$ the integral transforms to $\int_{f^{-1} (0)}^{f^{-1} (\pi)} y f'(y) dy$ which evaluates to $\pi(f^{-1} (\pi) -1)$ I couldn't get where I went wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $f(x):=\cos(x)+x$ is a strictly increasing map from $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover 
$$f(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)+\pi-x=\pi-f(x),$$
which implies that 
$$f^{-1}(f(\pi-f^{-1}(x)))=f^{-1}(\pi-f(f^{-1}(x)))\implies f^{-1}(\pi-x)+f^{-1}(x)=\pi.$$
Hence $I:=\int_0^{\pi} f^{-1}(x)dx=\int_0^{\pi} f^{-1}(\pi-x)dx$
and 
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}(f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(\pi-x))dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\pi dx=\frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$

Comment: No. $f^{-1}(\pi)\approx 3.881$. Your result is not correct. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

Comment: Why $\int_{f^{-1} (0)}^{f^{-1} (\pi)} y f'(y) dy=\pi(f^{-1} (\pi) -1)$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: [Using this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478525) 
you get $$\color{red}{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)  dx +\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dx  = bf(b) - af(a).}$$

that is:
$$\int_0^\pi f^{-1} (x) dx = f^{-1}(\pi)\pi- \int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(\pi)} f(x) dx = f^{-1}(\pi)\pi- \int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(\pi)}[\cos x +x] dx $$

I doubt that one could fine $f^{−1}(π)$ and $f^{−1}(0)$.

Comment: @user471651 I doubt that one could fine $f^{-1} (\pi)$ and $f^{-1} (0)$. But rater you can manipulate the original of $f$ trying to express in term of $f$.

Comment: @user471651 SEE THE EDIT iT GIVE YOUR RESULT WHEN SWICHING THE BOUND

Comment: The question is correct and $f(\pi)\pi- \int_{0}^{\pi}[\cos x +x] dx $ is NOT equal to $\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}$.